# How to use sendkeys command for all streams using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning python selenium multithread, now i can open multiple threads at the same time but when run sendkeys command it only populates 1 single thread. I tried using `driver.switch_to.window()` but it didn't work because it affected other threads and not separate operation. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot, below is my code

```
def open_browser():
    uc.TARGET_VERSION = 113
    opts = uc.ChromeOptions()

    global driver
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=opts, enable_cdp_events=True, version_main=113)

def doing_task(thread_num, name, password, driver):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 90).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'regEmail'))
    )
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'regEmail').send_keys(name)
    print(f'Thread {thread_num}: Username={name}, Password={password}')
    sleep(100)

def run(index, thread_num, df):
    name = df['Username'].iloc[index]
    password0 = df['Password'].iloc[index]
    with uc.Chrome() as driver:
        driver.get('https://www.reddit.com/register/')
        doing_task(thread_num, name, password0, driver)


def process_file(file_path, num_threads):
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    threads = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        thread_num = (index % num_threads) + 1
        thread = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(index, thread_num, df))
        threads.append(thread)
        if len(threads) == num_threads:
            for t in threads:
                t.start()
            for t in threads:
                t.join()
            threads = []
    
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()


def select_file():
    global file_path
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    file_label.config(text=file_path)

def select_num_threads(num_threads):
    global selected_threads
    selected_threads = int(num_threads)

def run_processing():
    process_thread = threading.Thread(target=process_file, args=(file_path, selected_threads))
    process_thread.start()

def create_interface():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Excel Processor")
    window.geometry("400x250")
    select_file_button = tk.Button(text="Select Excel File", command=select_file)
    select_file_button.pack(pady=10)
    global file_label
    file_label = tk.Label(window, text="")
    file_label.pack()
    dropbox_label = tk.Label(window, text="Select number of threads:")
    dropbox_label.pack()
    OPTIONS = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
    variable = tk.StringVar(window)
    variable.set(OPTIONS[0])
    dropbox_menu = tk.OptionMenu(window, variable, *OPTIONS, command=select_num_threads)
    dropbox_menu.pack()
    run_button = tk.Button(text="Run", command=run_processing)
    run_button.pack(pady=10)
    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    selected_threads = 1
    interface_thread = threading.Thread(target=create_interface)
    interface_thread.start()
```

Comment: Selenium WebDriver is not thread-safe. You can try to use `concurrent.futures` module to handle threading and a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.